# Switch case for comparing values

Tags: javascript

I want to use switch case for the values.
How can i compare values in case like `<=` or `>=`

```
 case<240:
```

It gives error...
thanks.

Comment: Can you really not even look up how the [switch statement works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) yourself?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with an `if` statement?

Comment: What's wrong with if blocks. Is there any reason you only want to use switch? If you want clean code, you can take advantage that js is a dynamic language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible.
Here's an example:

```
var x = 5;

switch (true) {
    case (x < 240):
        alert("Less than 240");
        break;
    case (x >= 240):
        alert("Greater than or equal to 240");
        break;
}
```

Comment: torazaburo: Thanks for pointing it out, yes it should be 'greater than'. Also, parentheses are optional, but I used them for ease of readability.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

```
switch (true) {
    case x < 240:
        /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to compare with some value in this case and use space in between:

```
var x=100;

switch(true) {
    case x < 100:
        alert("Less than 100");
        break;
    case (x >= 100):
        alert("greater or equal to 100");
        break;
}
```